# How can I test a java program on Unix from Windows?

Tags: java, windows, unix

Problem: I am developing a tool that does some file operations in Unix environment, but my development environment being Windows, how can I test what i am doing.

Is there any way I can simulate my program running in a Unix environment only for testing purpose?

Comment: why can't you install java on your Unix and port your codebase and test it there?

Comment: I guess you are developing at home. Try if Linux does your work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run a virtual machine such as [VMware](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) installed with Linux to test your program.

If you are on the same network as a Linux machine you can VNC into one and test your program remotely.

Answer (score 4):

Java is cross-platform (thanks to the JVM), so you don't need to worry about OS-specific details, with one exception: Directory separators.  Windows uses `\` and Unix uses `/`.  In order to ensure full compatibilty, you'll want to use the [separator in File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator).

Comment: If you use forward slashes in Java it will work under windows as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can run Ubuntu without install it. [Run it from disk or even USB](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/try-ubuntu-before-you-install).

Answer (score 1):

You can:

install the Linux on [`virtual machine`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine)

download some distribution that can run in [`live cd`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD);

install the Linux on your hard disk(that's a good thing :-) ), in [`multi boot`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi_boot);